# Binding in XAML (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I writing app for UWP platform

Have this code for binding:

```
namespace Milano.Classes
{
    public class InWorkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<RootObject> ordersList;

        public List<RootObject> OrdersList
        {
            get { return ordersList; }
            set { ordersList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private RootObject ordersChange;

        public RootObject OrdersChange
        {
            get { return ordersChange;}
            set { ordersChange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public  InWorkViewModel()
        {
            Inwork_down();
        }

        public async void  Inwork_down()
        {

            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            //Get all products
            var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                          { "per_page", "100" }, { "status","processing"} }); // Dodelat filtr dlaya teh chto v  rabote

            string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();
            Debug.WriteLine(products);

            List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);

            OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public class Billing
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shipping
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public int variation_id { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string tax_class { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double subtotal { get; set; }
        public double subtotal_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
        public List<object> meta { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShippingLine
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string method_title { get; set; }
        public string method_id { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int parent_id { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string order_key { get; set; }
            public string currency { get; set; }
            public string version { get; set; }
            public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
            public string date_created { get; set; }
            public string date_modified { get; set; }
            public int customer_id { get; set; }
            public double discount_total { get; set; }
            public double discount_tax { get; set; }
            public double shipping_total { get; set; }
            public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
            public double cart_tax { get; set; }
            public double total { get; set; }
            public double total_tax { get; set; }
            public Billing billing { get; set; }
            public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
            public string payment_method { get; set; }
            public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
            public string transaction_id { get; set; }
            public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
            public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
            public string created_via { get; set; }
            public string customer_note { get; set; }
            public string date_completed { get; set; }
            public string date_paid { get; set; }
            public string cart_hash { get; set; }
            public List<LineItem> line_items { get; set; }
            public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
            public List<ShippingLine> shipping_lines { get; set; }
            public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
            public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
        }

}
```

I need to take LineItem and write it to another list like I do it for OrdersChange,      for Binding it in XAML.

UPDATE1

Here is my XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Milano.InWork"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Milano"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" BorderBrush="#FFF5F1F1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Menu-100.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="logoutbutton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,650,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="43" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Logout_Button.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="63,2,-121,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338" BorderBrush="#FFFDFDFD" Padding="0,0,0,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="В Работе" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="1218" FontSize="32" FontFamily="SF UI Display" Padding="550,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <ListView x:Name="OrderList"  ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding OrdersChange, Mode=TwoWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="MyClick"  
                      >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid x:Name="GridInf"  RightTapped="Grid_RightTapped"   Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="667" Margin="415,54,-124,-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989">
        <ListView x:Name="DetailsList">
            <StackPanel Height="667" Width="989">
                 <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"  Height="667" Width="989"  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Время и дата заказа" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="214" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="vremyazakaza" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.date_created}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Статус" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.status }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Осталось времени" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ostalosvremeni" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="На когда" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="nakogda" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.billing.city}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Сумма" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="summa" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.total}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Имя" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White"  FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Телефон" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="telephone" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.billing.phone}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,308,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Адрес" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="adress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.billing.addres}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Количество персон" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="kolichestvoperson" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.billing.postcode}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Откуда" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="otkuda" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" Сайт" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,440,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Состав заказа" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button x:Name="sostavzakaza" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23" Content="Просмотреть состав"  />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,484,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Приметка для кухни" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PrimetkaKuhni" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.customer_note}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,528,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Приметка для курьера" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PrimetkaKuriera" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                            </Grid>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="0,572,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Id Транзакции" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="IDTranz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.transaction_id}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>







</Grid>
```

How I can do this?

Thank's for help.

Comment: to clarify your question: as I understand, you want to bind the List<LineItem> you have from a certain instance of root object to a UI element (listview)?

Comment: yes, you are right @Radinator

Comment: I don't get your problem. just do it as you do it with the OrdersChange. Define in the XAML file a new listview, set ItemSource, DisplayMemberPath and (if you like) SelectedItem

Comment: btw please show some code, how you bind OrdersChange

Comment: I updated question. Problem In that, list if products (line_items) in OrdersList.

I need to take it and write to another list.

Because when I write `="{Binding OrdersChange.line_items.sku}"` nothin is binding. @Radinator

Comment: I think you want to select an item and show its details in another `ListView`?